# Display the names of selected checkboxes and the values

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display the name of all the selected check boxes and their values. At the moment it shows the values of all the selected check boxes but not the name of the selected check box. How would I do this?

The sections of code are below. The HTML form section has 9 identical checkboxes apart from the name and value.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['jan'];
echo $_POST['feb'];
echo $_POST['mar'];
echo $_POST['apr'];
echo $_POST['may'];
echo $_POST['jun'];
echo $_POST['jul'];
echo $_POST['aug'];
echo $_POST['sep'];
?>

<div class="checkbox">
<label>$15 :     
<input name="jan" value="15" type="checkbox"> January
</label>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: this isn't full code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why would you need it all?

Comment: you've been given an answer below. Seeing *"some green"* next to it will be a bonus ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox parameters are only set if the box is checked. So test whether it's set:

```
if (isset($_POST['jan'])) {
    echo 'jan: ' . $_POST['jan'];
}
```

You can put this into a loop:

```
$months = array('jan', 'feb', ...);
foreach ($months as $m) {
    if (isset($_POST[$m])) {
        echo $m . ': ' . $_POST[$m];
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG Thankyou! I only checked if the form was actually submitted. I see now I need to check each checkbox. Thankyou.

Comment: Haha one step ahead of you with the loop but thanks anyway. Have some green.